# How to write Azure Cognitive Services Speech audio output to an Azure Blob?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services

My goal is to use an Azure Function to get some text files from a blob with a trigger, pass these text files to Azure Cognitive Services text-to-speech and get back audio and save it in a blob container. I have been trying with numerous ways but I can't get the audio written back in a blob. Currently the error I am getting is
`"Blob stream has already been committed once"`

I am trying with the below code. I cannot figure out how to write the returned audio to the outputBlob that is a `Stream`

```
[FunctionName("TextToSpeechFunction")]
    public static async void Run([BlobTrigger("input/{name}", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]Stream myBlob,
        [Blob("output/a", FileAccess.Write)] Stream outputBlob, string name, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
        var data = await SynthesizeAudioAsync();
        await outputBlob.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
    }

    static async Task<byte[]> SynthesizeAudioAsync()
    {
        var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("XXXYYYZZZZ", "northeurope");
        var synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer(config, null);
        var result = await synthesizer.SpeakTextAsync("Getting the response as an in-memory stream.");
        var buffer = result.AudioData;
        return buffer;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying with the below code. I cannot figure out how to write the returned audio to the outputBlob that is a `Stream`

For this, you can read data from the audio data stream and process it in memory. Below is the code that worked for me.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace TextToSpeech
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        private const string Key = "<YOUR_KEY>";
        private const string Location = "<YOUR_LOCATION>"; // Azure Speech Service Location
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task ConvertTextToSpeech([BlobTrigger("speechcontainer/{name}", Connection = "")] Stream myBlob, [Blob("speech/audio", FileAccess.Write)] Stream outputBlob, string name, ILogger log, ExecutionContext context)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
            var confg = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(Key, Location);

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(myBlob);
            string blobContent = reader.ReadToEnd();

            using (var converter = new SpeechSynthesizer(confg))
            {
                using (var r = await converter.SpeakTextAsync(blobContent))
                {
                    if (r.Reason == ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Speech synthesized for text {name}.");

                        using (var audioDataStream = AudioDataStream.FromResult(r))
                        {                          
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[16000];
                            uint totalSize = 0;
                            uint filledSize = 0;

                            while ((filledSize = audioDataStream.ReadData(buffer)) > 0)
                            {
                                totalSize += filledSize;
                                await outputBlob.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                            }

                            Console.WriteLine($"{totalSize} bytes of audio data received for {name}");
                        }
                    }
                    else if (r.Reason == ResultReason.Canceled)
                    {
                        var canc = SpeechSynthesisCancellationDetails.FromResult(r);
                        Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: " + $"Reason={canc.Reason}");
                        if (canc.Reason == CancellationReason.Error)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"Cancelled with " + $"Error Code {canc.ErrorCode}");
                            Console.WriteLine($"Cancelled with " + $"Error Details " + $"[{canc.ErrorDetails}]");
                        }
                    }
                }               
                Console.WriteLine("Text To Speech Successfully Completed !!!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**RESULT:**

[image]

[image]

**REFERENCES:-**
[cognitive-services-speech-sdk](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/samples/csharp/sharedcontent/console/speech_synthesis_samples.cs)